# Cannot connect PowerBI Desktop and PowerBI WebApp with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to connect PowerBI Desktop with Google Analytics.

I am getting this error message, below is the screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Similarly, if I try to connect to Google Analytics with PowerBI WebApp, then as well, I am getting the same issues.

I have following configurations:

1. Google Chrome v72
2. Microsoft Internet explorer v11
3. Windows 7 as OS. (haha.. that's true)
4. As per the error message; I have deleted all of my credentials, cleared cache, deleted all password, and only have one Google Account where I use Google Analytics.

I've also asked my colleagues, but they get the same error message on PowerBI Desktop and PowerBI WebApp.

Please suggest the solution.

Comment: This doesn't look like something you can fix. Probably this issue will be fixed in future version or it is just temporary.

Comment: I see. I asked here because I thought probably I am doing something wrong, or there is some fix available. Not sure, if others too, are facing the same issue.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: I understand that its not about solving a programming issue; but the thing is, I couldn't even find an answer on Microsoft Community page. https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Integrations-with-Files-and/Can-t-connect-to-Google-analytics/m-p/474188#M18620 They mention that this issue is fixed, but it still appears; and there isn't any updates from Microsoft. That's the reason I asked here.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I restarted my computer and then it worked like a charm. :)